# imagemagick is executed in /usr/bin but the new version is in /usr/local/bin - php exec path

Tags: php, linux, path, centos, exec

It seems the problem I have is that imagemagick is being executed from /usr/bin in which an old version of imagemagick is installed on my server, I do not know how to make php exec() look in the right direction which is /usr/local/bin - that is the actual location of convert,
if I try using the full path with exec /usr/local/bin/convert then it does not work, exits with 127

I am on php 5.3.3 on cent os 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing this?

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/convert ...
```

Comment: yes, it exits exec with error code 127

Comment: Are you sure about the location? Have you tried running it from shell?

Comment: It worked well, I had two instances opened of the same document on which I was making the edits to the convert string and I was editing on the wrong file, thanks